# Prolog Tube map Same Line

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and i am very confused about how to go about doing this, your help will help me understand what i have to do for further tasks as well.

I have to check if two stations are on the same line and which line that is,
Here are the Locations:

```
% Locations %

%Central Line 

location(nh,central).
location(lg,central).
location(oc,central).
location(tc,central).
location(cl,central).
location(ls,central).
location(bg,central).

% victoria 
location(br,victoria).
location(vi,victoria).
location(oc,victoria).
location(ws,victoria).
location(kx,victoria).
location(fp,victoria).

% Northern 
location(eu,northern).
location(ws,northern).
location(tc,northern).
location(em,northern).
location(ke,northern).

% Metropolitan
location(fr,metropolitan).
location(bs,metropolitan).
location(kx,metropolitan).
location(ls,metropolitan).
location(al,metropolitan).

% Bakerloo 
location(wa,bakerloo).
location(pa,bakerloo).
location(oc,bakerloo).
location(em,bakerloo).
location(ec,bakerloo).
```

so i need to make a sameLine() rule to check if the two station are on the same line and what line it is. I was thinking of doing :

```
sameLine(location1,location2,line) :-
    location(location1,line),
    location(location2,line).
```

Does that check if the two stations are on the same line? and how how would i show what line it is?

Comment: Do you know that variables in Prolog must start with a capital letter or `_`? So your `sameLine/3` definition is incorrect. Otherwise, what `sameLine/3` does is succeed if `Location1` and `Location2` are both on line `Line`.

Comment: Do u mean that the variables should be Location(). or location(FR,Metropolitan). ??? as i said i am completely nw with near 0 knowledge.

Comment: `location(...)` is a predicate, not a variable. You need, for example, `sameLine(Location1, Location2, Line)`. Check the Prolog introductory documentation for proper syntax in Prolog. Especially since you are a beginner, documentation and tutorials are your friend.

Comment: Wow, your prof sucks. Like five guys from your class have showed up here asking for help on this one question in the last week.

Comment: `sameline/3` will work if you capitalize your variables. Right now you have atoms, and it won't work. E.g. `sameLine(Location1, Location2, Line) :- ...`